# Error Logging into Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

After pressing the log in button it would said updating minecraft and after that it said
`Failed to launch`
`Fatal error occurred (4): null`
I have forced an update and updated Java but it still doesn't work. Not even the demo works.

Comment: It's possible that something may be blocking the download. Take a look at your firewall settings and see if that's the problem.

Comment: Is this a fresh install, or one that worked previously?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your antivirus/firewall. Apparently Avira 2012 and McAfee have been known to prevent the connection to Minecraft update servers.

[Here is one such report](http://minecraftirc.net/thread-35-post-53.html#pid53)

If you're comfortable doing this, you could try temporarily disabling your antivirus while Minecraft updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, and I had to delete my `minecraft.jar` to get there.

For Windows: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Then inside the text box type `%appdata%`. Go to your `.minecraft` folder and find your `bin` folder, and inside of that delete `minecraft.jar`. Then open the Minecraft launcher and click "options", then click "Force Update". Then log in to Minecraft, and done.